# My wooden pressure plates aren't deactivating

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Ever since the 1.6.2 update, if something activates a wooden Pressure Plate it will stay activated.

It only happens on one world, and even then only in 2 chunks (my HUGE survival world).

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Diagram or screenshot of the redstone? There may be something else powering the circuit. Redstone repeaters for example have a bad habit of keeping a circuit on after it has been triggered if it exists in a loop.

Comment: I will add a picture ASAP when my computer it back up and running(I'm using my Chromebook) and it is just a wooden pressure plate with redstone next to it or under it.

Comment: Try using an earlier version of Minecraft to see if the problem is still there.

Comment: Try breaking and re-placing the pressure plates and redstone circuitry. I've found sometimes when updating a world something goes a little... funky. Especially when it comes to redstone.

Comment: Is it on a single player world or a server [that you are hosting]?

Comment: It is on a single player world.

Comment: @Robotnik I make the redstone bug over and over and it did the same thing.

Comment: Post a screenie and we'll check it out.

Comment: I'm in 1.7 I'm having the same problem when I create a super flat world it's perfect but when I create a reagular one it's laggy as if I have a virus But my laptops 10 tears old

Comment: Considering that it only happens in two chunks, I'd say this is a corrupted chunk issue. But screenshots will help :)

Answer (score 1):

Resorath is right in saying that the connected circuit may be activated, not the pressure plate. To tell the difference, press F3 and look at the pressure plate when it should not be activated but appears to be, and check if "activated" is set to "true."

Answer (score -3):

Try destroying the pressure plate, then replace it.

Comment: This wouldn't work unfortunatly